# If $\Pi: G\rightarrow \{1, -1\}$ with ker$\Pi=H$ then $[G:H]=2$ for $H\leq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If

(1) $\Pi: G\rightarrow \{1, -1\}$ with ker$\Pi=H$ then

(2) $[G:H]=2$ for $H\leq G$? Also then for

(3) $a, b\notin H$  implies $ab\in H$?

I think these are equivalent. $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$

Can you give me a hint to prove this?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$

First isomorphism theorem

$(2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$

If $a,b \not\in H$, then $b^{-1}aH= H \Leftrightarrow aH=bH$